# JSR 352 Partitioned Chunk Processing

Tags: java, spring-batch, jsr, jsr352

I am trying to run a chunk step (Reader - Processor - Writer) in Spring Batch in JSR 352 Mode. I wanted to know if partitioning creates a new instance of the batch Artifacts (`MyItemReader`) for every partition or are the artifacts stateful (i.e global variables defined in the artifacts are reused for multiple threads and not thread safe)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per section 11.1 of JSR-352, each partition should have it's own instance of all batch artifacts.